# Automation testing on OS level

Tags: ios, automated-tests, iphone-privateapi, eggplant

I am working on an iOS application in which automation testing will be done on OS level( can open any application through script). I have searched a lot, all I found is we are allowed to automate the test script within our own application only. Okay, My question is How the EggPlant is able to automate the test on OS level( can open contacts, phone application through scripts)?

Note: This will be an in-House enterprise application and not destined for apple app store.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile test automation tools use vendor provided APIs to interact with operating system. For iOS it's [UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html).

Comment: Does UI Automation allows for System level interaction?

Comment: In simple words, Can i open any application through UI Automation scripts? In my knowledge, we can run automation scripts within our app only.

Comment: I haven't worked directly with UI Automation but for example with Appium, which uses UI Automation API to run the iOS tests, you can open any application on iOS. Take a look here for some example Appium tests for the Preferences app on iOS: https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/test/functional/ios/prefs

Answer (score 1):

You can only automate what is within the binary of your application. For instance, if your app uses a web view you can access the internet, but you cannot exit your application from the automation test and open Safari. EggPlant doesn't operate based on the binary of your application, it "looks" at the screen and executes gestures or processes based on what it sees.

Comment: I agree EggPlant is using image recognition to search anything on the device screen. My Question is how the iPhone is able to execute the SenseTalk commands ?

Comment: The SenseTalk commands are executed against the computer, not jus the simulator. UIAutomation is just executed against the binary of the app. With EggPlant, anything that is on screen is tappable, so iPhone itself is not executing the commands,, it's just like when you are interacting with the simulator.